# Change graph from checkboxInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have started learning Shiny and I am not sure How can I do this.

I want to pass the value of my checkboxInput as an argument of my function `cum_in`  and then see my graph in my dashboard. But I am not sure How can I do this.
This is my code:

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
source(R/cum_income.R)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Prueba Back-End",
          collapsible = T, width = 12,
          column( 12,align="center" ,tableOutput('top5')),
        plotOutput("plot2", height = 250))
      
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(
        selectInput("v_states", label = "Estados", choices = v_states, multiple = TRUE),
        checkboxInput("all", "Select All/None", value = TRUE)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #CheckBox 
  out_graph <- reactive({
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      cum_inc(select_state = input$checkboxInput,
              data = "df_covid_ssa_state_zmvm",
              outcome = c("Confirmados", "Síntomas"),
              type = "cum_cases",
              select_trans = "identity")
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to pass the vector of states from the checkboxInput result in the first argument `select_state`

`v_states` is a vector where I have the name of 32 states

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the outer reactive should make it work (I can't verify since data and function are missing):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      cum_inc(select_state = input$checkboxInput,
              data = "df_covid_ssa_state_zmvm",
              outcome = c("Confirmados", "Síntomas"),
              type = "cum_cases",
              select_trans = "identity")
    })
}
```

Comment: When I tried this is my output ```object 'gg_outcome' not found ``` If I try to run my function ``` cum_in() ``` with specific arguments everything is working but When I try to implement the checkbox it fails

Comment: Difficult to say without the function code and data. Also I'm not sure why you pass the dataframe to the function as a string.

Comment: The code of the function is very long this is why I didn´t append but ``` v_states <- c("Aguascalientes", "Baja California", "Baja California Sur")``` this is the reason why I want a checkboxInput to select the states that I want to visualize and then pass this vector as argument to my function